# How to package fonts in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, font-management

Is it possible to export an Illustrator file off our MAC (CS6) and send to PC (Adobe CC) and package all the fonts to go with the artwork to avoid installing missing fonts one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Not with CS6. Only with Illustrator CC.

[image]

For Illustrator CS6 there are third party plug ins such as [Scoop](http://www.worker72a.com/pages/SCP.html), or [Art Files](http://www.code-line.com/artfiles/), which will collect links and fonts for you.

Comment: If this is correct (and it seems to be), it would appear that Adobe's own documentation is incorrect: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/package-files.html : _"This feature is available in Adobe Illustrator CS6, CC, and later."_

Comment: @Brandon I **guarantee** it's not part of Illustrator CS6 on the Mac. I'm looking at it right now...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script that packages all the assets related to the document (like linked images), but it unfortunately doesn't collect the fonts along.

**Using the Collect for Output script:**

1. Open the document that you want to package/collect for output.
2. On the menu, go `File > Scripts > Other Script`
3. The execute script panel will pop up. In OSX, the script will be
   located on `\Applications\Adobe Illustrator CS5\Scripting\Sample
   Scripts\Applescript\Collect for Output\` .
4. Choose `CollectForOutput.scpt`
5. Now follow the directions (it will ask to save the document first
   and then for a destination folder)

Finding out what fonts are being used in a giving document:
Use Adobe Bridge (which should have been installed along with Illustrator).

1. browse to the file you want to get information about within Bridge.
2. Select the file
3. Open the metadata panel.
4. Voila! All the info you might need: Fonts, swatches, etc.

Hope it helps. CS5 users: the collect for output script is also available to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been happy using [ArtFiles](http://www.code-line.com/artfiles/) to package my AI6 projects. It's easy to use and works great. Just open the program and drag in the file. It also lets you know of any potential errors. The free trial version allows you to use it 15 times… after that it's $39.95. It's been well worth it for me.

Answer (score 0):

in Illustrator cs6 with Mac.

To find fonts go to

1. menu type - find font - there is a list with all the fonts used on the document.
2. Launch the application Font Book located in application menu, search your font - right click on font - show in finder - copy paste.

Answer (score -1):

i am still using CS6- too much money for not enough benefit to upgrade to CC- and just downloaded ArtFiles to collect images and fonts for a large project. worked amazingly well- highly recommend this as a work-around for those who have the occasional need to packge up AI files.