# What is the equivalent to Corel's "Collect for Output" in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

Hi everyone I have been using Corel for years. I just started using illustrator though, and need to know, when I finish the design for print what to do. Currently, some fonts and images go missing. My question is can't we save all document including fonts and images in one shot. In Corel Draw there is an option called `Collect for output` that will collect all those stuff which we used to design. How is this done in Illustrator?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Please review [our help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to see how to get the most of the Graphic Design StackExchange. For instance, the title of your question is so vague as to be unuseable to others on the site. Consider editing it to be more precise like, "Does Illustrator have the capability of collecting and packaging all the artwork's resources?" I also suggest reworking the body of your question as right now it is very hard to read and understand.

Comment: "Does Illustrator have the capability of collecting and packaging all the artwork's resources?"

Comment: @ShaikEmraan I already edited your question to something people might be willing to help you with. I'd suggest leaving it how it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to package fonts in Illustrator CS6?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30655/how-to-package-fonts-in-illustrator-cs6)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In Illustrator CC or newer choose `File > Package`

[image]

Possible duplicate: [How to package fonts in Illustrator CS6?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30655/how-to-package-fonts-in-illustrator-cs6/30795#30795)

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have a clearer question to work from the answer is, no. Illustrator does not have the same functionality as Corel Draw's "Collect for Output". **But** Illustrator does have the ability to save as a PDF. PDF's embed all the content inside the PDF "container" and this includes the fonts and images used. This saving as a PDF functionally accomplishes the same thing as "Package for Output".

Edit: Apparently Illustrator CC has the ability to package the artwork and all its resources. See [Scott's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46025/34631) to see how to access this feature.